# Gorm not returning ErrRecordNotFound

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have the following code

```
func (r *WorkspaceRepository) Delete(id any) (bool, error) {
    if err := r.db.Where("id = ?", id).Delete(&model.Workspace{}).Error; err != nil {
        return false, err
    }

    return true, nil
}
```

When I pass an ID that does not exist, no errors are returned, as if the record existed!

What do I need to do to check before deleting, do I need to do a SELECT first?

Answer (score 7):

Delete method does not return ErrRecordNotFound error. Docs here: https://gorm.io/docs/error_handling.html

*GORM returns ErrRecordNotFound when failed to find data with **First, Last, Take***

Code:

```
r.db.Where("id = ?", id).Delete(&model.Workspace{})
```

return gorm.DB struct and you can check if any item deleted or not

```
 tx := r.db.Where("id = ?", id).Delete(&model.Workspace{})

 fmt.Println(tx.RowsAffected)
```